# CodeIgniter trying to use parent

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a MY_Controller class with this property:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public $_template;
    protected $_view;
    ...
    //Some methods here
}
```

I have the Profille Controller:

```
class profile extends MY_Controller {

    protected $_view = 'consultoria/profile';
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function index() {
        $this->_template->build($this->_view);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to use parent:: instead of $this on index()

```
parent::_template->build($this->_view)
```

The error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in C:\xampp\htdocs\officeprime\application\controllers\consultoria\profile.php on line 18
```

Why I can't use parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You double colon `::` for static, contant properties or methods. Use `$this->` instead of `parent::`. For eaching any of your parent class elements in CI just use `$this->`